# Use of undeclared type 'FIRMessagingDelegate', 'Messaging' and 'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage'.

Tags: ios, firebase, notifications

I'm searching for a long time and no answers solved my problem.
I'm following a Firebase tutorial for push notifications and implemented the AppDelegate code.

But Xcode didn't recognize 'FIRMessagingDelegate', 'Messaging' and 'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage'.

I had tried update repo, recreate, etc..

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //FirebaseApp.configure() - Documentação 
    FIRApp.configure()

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}

//More code..

}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo


        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo


        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
}


extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    // [START refresh_token]
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
    }
// [END refresh_token]
// [START ios_10_data_message]
// Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
// To enable direct data messages, you can set Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true.
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
    // [END ios_10_data_message]
} //*/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of Firebase are you using? According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Classes/FIRMessaging), class names changes for Firebase 4.0.0 in Swift. So `FIRMessagingDelegate`, is now `MessagingDelegate`, and so on. See the migration guide [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/naming-migration-guide)

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have latest version of firebase push notifications lib.
Some of their old stuff are being deprecated and removed.
Also chek in Project `Navigator/Pods.xcodeproj/Targets` if those pods are installed in your project, if not add them into your `Podfile`

Answer (score 0):

`FIRMessagingRemoteMessage` is updated to `MessagingRemoteMessage`